# Custom name in redis cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am using `Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis version: 2.1.2.RELEASE`.
I need to give name of cache according to parameter passed in method.My code sample is given below:

```
@Cacheable(value = "Company"+"-"+"#companyId",key="#employeeId")
public Employee getEmployee(Long companyId, Long employeeId) {
    //Some code here

        }
```

I **expected the name** like `Company-1` 
but actual result is `Company-#companyId`.
I'm searching something like customKeyGenerator.
Please give me your suggestions.TIA

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that using "Company"+"-"+"#companyId" won't work because 'value' interprets everything as string. 'key' accepts Spring Expression Language (SpEL) expression for computing the key dynamically and hence #employeeId works. 
You need a custom cacheResolver : 
[spring cache with custom cacheResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985340/spring-cache-with-custom-cacheresolver)

Comment: How can I change name of cache using `CustomCacheManager`. You gave me good starting point but in given example name is not being change.